# Select all records when no value is supplied

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function in php that does retrieval and display work from a MySql database.

It's like this:

```
function thisFunction($id,$country,$year){
global $conn;
    $conn = connect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from table where id = :id and countryCode = :country and YEAR(addedDate) = :year and status = 0");
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':id'      => $id,             
        ':country' => $location,
        ':year'    => $year
    ));
}
```

The problem is, sometimes `$id` has a value, sometimes it doesn't. When it does have a value, I'd like to select records with that value, when it doesn't I'd like to select all.

How do I write the sql in there, or do this thing, so that when there is a value it'll select only records with that value, and when there isn't a value, it'll select all. It's the part where when no value is selected - then select all where I'm stuck.

I call the function like anyone would. Nothing unique there.

```
select * from table where id = 9 -- works fine - displays all records where id = 9
select * from table where id = no value supplies - should display all value. How do I do this?
```

Can you please help?

```
select * from table where id = * //Does not work
```

Comment: Build your query as a string, check if `$id` is not empty, add or skip the condition (and the `:id` parameter) based on that.

Comment: Wildcards is the word I wanted to use.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the id part if it's empty:

```
function thisFunction($id,$country,$year){
    global $conn;

    $conn = connect();

    if (!isset($id) || empty($id))
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from table where countryCode = :country and YEAR(addedDate) = :year and status = 0");
        $stmt->execute(array(      
            ':country' => $location,
            ':year'    => $year
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from table where id = :id and countryCode = :country and YEAR(addedDate) = :year and status = 0");
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':id'      => $id,             
            ':country' => $location,
            ':year'    => $year
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: And if it isn't? Sometimes, the `id` in the function has a value, sometimes it wont. When there's no value I need to select all. Can't remove the `id` from in there.

Comment: I have modified the code that will check whether the id is set/empty or not and execute the correct query depending on that condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where id = id;
```

[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a94bd/4)

Comment: @anonymous downvoter: Any comment. Did you checked the fiddle?

Comment: My question is, using your `table` and `data` and the same `sql` you supplied above, when there's no value for id, how can I get it to return all rows? Eg: `select * from table where id = 1` - fine. But if `select * from table where id = no value supplied here` - then return all rows.

Comment: to return all rows, either you shouldn't submit any value or you need to pass id as it is

Comment: `either you shouldn't submit any value` This is what I need. But how?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
function thisFunction($id,$country,$year){

    global $conn;

    $sql_query = "select * from table where status = 0";

    $where_data = array();

    if(isset($id) && $id != '*'){ // Only add this if ID is set to something other than *
        $where_data[':id'] = $id;
        $sql_query .= " AND id = :id";
    }

    if(isset($location)){
        $where_data[':country'] = $location;
        $sql_query .= " AND countryCode = :country";
    }

    if(isset($year)){
        $where_data[':year'] = $year;
        $sql_query .= " AND YEAR(addedDate) = :year"; 
    }

    $conn = connect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_query);
    $stmt->execute($where_data);

}
```

Comment: You need to take `id = :id` out of the `WHERE` clause if `$id` is not set.

Comment: @Barmar Pressed save before i finished!! Ooops. The SQL will now get built in the IF statements.

Comment: There's nothing in MySql like `id = *` or `id = NULL`. Something like that that'll get all values when no figure is supplied?

Answer (score 0):

you could potentially select them if the column is not null.

```
select * from table where id is not null
```